# Spring RestTemplate seems to not be thread-safe wrt headers

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thread-safety, resttemplate

I have a Spring web client which posts to a Spring web server (the same URL) using two different basic-auth users.  Is it a known issue that I can not use a single `RestTemplate` for both?

When I use a single `RestTemplate`, and the requests are nearly simultaneous (in different threads), though I specify different users in the header, the receiving server thinks they're from the same user!  Note that the request and the headers (and the body of the post) are newly allocated for each request.

It works fine, when I use a single `RestTemplate` and put a `synchronized()` around the call to

```
response = RestTemplate.exchange(url, method, requestParams, MyResponse.class)
```

I've also tried creating two `RestTemplate` instances, one for each user - (each built with a `RestTemplateBuilder`) that works, too.  I'll keep this solution, but it surprises me that it's needed.

Is this a known issue?

(I see stackOverflow answers that a `RestTemplate` is thread-safe after constructed, but the headers are passed in with the request, not as a setting on the already-constructed `RestTemplate`...)

====

Here's an example of 2 different calls, using 2 different RestTemplates because there were sometimes problems in using the same:

```
public OperationStatus getOpStatus(String gufi) {
    HttpEntity<String> requestParams = new HttpEntity<>(Utils.createBasicHeader(cfg.getManager(), cfg.getManPass()));
ResponseEntity<OperationStatus> restResponse = null;
try {
        restResponse = managerRestTemplate.exchange(
            cfg.getNussOpApiPath(),  HttpMethod.GET,  requestParams,  OperationStatus.class);
    } catch (RestClientException e) {
    ...
    }
    OperationStatus opState = restResponse.getBody();
    opState.setHttpStatusCode(String.valueOf(restResponse.getStatusCodeValue()));                                                                
    return opState;
}
```

Here was a method to do a post, using the priority to switch rest templates (at the time, the target server recognized the priority by the privileges of the user)

```
UTMRestResponse doPost(Object objToSend, String url, String msg) throws IOException {

    String user = cfg.getOpUser();
    String pass = cfg.getOpPass();
    RestTemplate restTemplate = opUserRestTemplate;
    boolean isPriorityOp = false;

    if ( objToSend instanceof OpPost) {
        OpPost post = (OpPost) objToSend;
        String flightNum = post.getFlightNumber();
        isPriorityOp = Boolean.TRUE.equals(post.getPriorityOp());  // null is false                                                                             
    } else if ( objToSend instanceof PositionPost) {
        PositionPost post = (PositionPost) objToSend;
        isPriorityOp = Boolean.TRUE.equals(post.getPriorityOp());  // null is false                                                                             
    }

    if (isPriorityOp) {
        user = cfg.getUserEmergency();
        pass = cfg.getPassEmergency();
        restTemplate = emergRestTemplate;
    }

    String jsonToSend = CommonsObjectMapper.get().writeValueAsString(objToSend);
    HttpEntity<String> requestParams = new HttpEntity<>(jsonToSend, Utils.createBasicHeader(user, pass));

    UTMRestResponse restResponse = restTemplate.exchange(
            url, HttpMethod.POST, requestParams, UTMRestResponse.class).getBody();
    if (restResponse.getHttpStatusCode().startsWith("4")) {
        String fmt = "Status:{}, url:{}, jsonSent:{}, response:{}";
        logger.error(fmt, restResponse.getHttpStatusCode(), url, jsonToSend, restResponse.getMsg());
    }
    return restResponse;
}
```

Comment: Please add the code you are using to construct the headers and pass the authentication. As mentioned by the documentation the `RestTemplate` is thread-safe, so it must be the way you are using the code that it breaks.

Comment: Any news on this issue please ?

Comment: I added some sample code. The workaround was to have one RestTemplate per user. The problem seemed to occur if two calls from two different users overlapped in time.  It was possible for two threads to overlap in time in any way. I tried and failed to make a simple test case. I've moved on to another project.